# What's the meaning of "start the clock"?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-king-of-the-monsters

In [*Godzilla King of the Monsters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla:_King_of_the_Monsters_(2019_film)) (2019), Colonel orders pilot to shoot Rodan, the fire demon which is approaching them back:

> Colonel: Gold Squadron, engage on our six.
>
> Pilot: Copy. **Start the clock**.

What's the meaning of "start the clock"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are attempting to lure Rodan toward "Monster Zero". The clock indicates the time when they'll arrive at the same place.

> “Argo to Gold Squadron,” Stanton broadcast. **“Let’s lure this turkey away from the mainland and straight toward Monster Zero – ETA, two minutes.”**
>
> “Copy,” the reply came back. The pilot was on-screen, along with his handle, Cobra. “Start the clock.”

The pilot is telling HQ (and everyone else) that they've started their plan and when they should expect it to have succeeded. About two minutes later, their plan is successful and the two monsters start trying to kill each other, at that point the mission clock would stop.